# Null pointer exception post submit of spring batch

Tags: annotations, spring-batch

Getting null pointer exception post submit of spring batch job.
Spring batch job has **EnableAsync** annotation and it is deployed on **Weblogic12.2.1.3**.

Same war is working fine on one server but not on another.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:738)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:797)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:713)
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.sendErrorIfNecessary(ErrorPag
> eFilter.java:355)
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.getOutputStream(ErrorPageFilt
> er.java:375)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.DelegateChunkWriter.getWriter(DelegateChunkWriter.java:155)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.DelegateChunkWriter.print(DelegateChunkWriter.java:119)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.print(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:190)
> at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspWriterImpl.print(JspWriterImpl.java:178)
> at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:274)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)